# How to create continuous loop in C where each iteration of the loop occurs once per iteration of the loop it's inside

Tags: loops, while-loop, statements

I'm creating a game in c. the game has a function called loop(), which calls other functions and has them update during each game loop.
The game character is simply a char image. 
The issue that i'm having, is that I want this char image to continuously move in a direction after 1 keypress is made, however, I can only seem to get it to move once per keypress, meaning it needs to be held down to get continuous movement.

Things I tried: 
I made a while loop, to specify that the char would continuously move until it hit a boundary on the screen...The issue I had here was the fact that the while loop was nested inside the entire games while loop, meaning that the nested loop, looped through all iterations inside the range of the nested loop before the outloop had executed it once, meaning the game character instantly jumped to the boundary of the game.

tried it with an if statement, which as expected only executes once.

I also tried to use boolean to read true once a keypress was made, and tried several different versions of this.

I just need ideas on how to get a char image to move continuously based on its stored velocity, and have the image step once per iteration of the entire game loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```c
int is_moving = 0, speed = 0;
char direction = '0';
while(1){ //game loop
    if(/* north keypress event */){
        is_moving = 1;
        speed = 1;
        direction = 'n';
    }
    else if(/* east keypress event */){
        is_moving = 1;
        speed = 1;
        direction = 'e';
    }
    else if(/* south keypress event */){
        is_moving = 1;
        speed = 1;
        direction = 's';
    }
    else if(/* west keypress event */){
        is_moving = 1;
        speed = 1;
        direction = 'w';
    }

    for(int steps = 0; steps < speed && is_moving; ++steps){
        /* movement logic and other checks go here */
    }
    ++speed;
}
```

Just make sure to set `is_moving` to `0` once the character should stop moving. Obviously this is just a simple example, but it sounds like you already have the directional component of the velocity figured out.
**Edit:**
Within the body of the for loop, you'll need to check the value of `direction` and then have the character move appropriately.

Comment: thank you, turns out my problem was the fact that I was initializing the variables that were the equivalents of is_moving and speed inside of the game loop, so they were re-initializing to zero for each game loop iterations which is why it was requiring me to hold the key!!

Comment: Hah, I almost made the same mistake when I was writing the code snippet for my answer. I'm glad you were able to figure out the problem.

Comment: haha, thanks again. Just a follow up to that first question, within this function, I actually have 4 different keypresses, which each result in that char heading in a different direction. I assumed I would've been able to extrapolate from the first situation to finish the problem off, however there seems to be some interaction problems between the loops. Any help appreciated :) thankyou

Comment: Thank you, seems so simple once you've been shown the way :)